# R: OIsurv "out of bounds" error

Tags: r, indexoutofboundsexception

Within the OIsurv package in R, why is it that

```
> my.surv <- Surv(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
> confBands(my.surv)
```

produces the error

```
Error in ep.c10[aU, aL]: Subscript out of bounds
```

while something like

```
> my.surv <- Surv(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
> confBands(my.surv)
```

works perfectly fine?